# Dependency Version is missing - 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.vertx:vertx-stack-depchain:jar is missing

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml, vert.x

Trying to specify my vertx version for different modules in the parent pom.
My parent pom file is:

```
<groupId>com.abc.xyc</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Parent POM</name>

<modules>
    ...
    <module>Server</module>
    ...
</modules>

<properties>
    ...
    <vertx.version>3.8.2</vertx.version>
    <vertx.verticle>com.abc.xyc.as4.MainVerticle</vertx.verticle>
    <vertx-maven-plugin.version>1.0.22</vertx-maven-plugin.version>
    <lmax.version>3.4.2</lmax.version>
    ...
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-stack-depchain</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
        <pluginManagement>
            ...
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.reactiverse</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vertx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${vertx-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>vmp</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>initialize</goal>
                                <goal>package</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <redeploy>true</redeploy>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManageme>
</build>
```

This is my child pom file

```
<artifactId>Server</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.abc.xyc</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-stack-depchain</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ... 
</dependencies>
```

The error I get is:'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.vertx:vertx-stack-depchain:jar is missing. When I specify the version in child pom, it works fine. My question is why isn't it getting the version from my parent pom?

Answer (score 2):

It's because it does not "manage" its own version, it manages other dependencies via `<dependencyManagement>`.

In general, there is no need to import the `vertx-stack-depchain` as a depenedency, it should be a `parent` or like you did in dependency-management with `<scope>import</scope>` and then you can do things like the following in your child poms:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you still find a good reason to import the dep-chain itself, then you need to specify the version.